# How to get last "example" item in ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arraylist

I need to show my only last item of "example" from an ArrayList. For example I have list of fruits like this :

1) apple

2) apple

3) apple   --> I need to show this

4) grape

5) Mango

how to show them like this?

1) apple

2) grape

3) mango

thank you.

Comment: Do you mean only unique items? Why don't use Set instead of List?

Comment: not only unique items. so if an arraylist contains "apple" or "grape" more than once, i need to show last item of "apple" or "grape"

Comment: `Set<String> uniqueItems = new HashSet<String>(list);`. This will print only unique items..

Comment: Thank you, can i also get position/index of item in arraylist?

Comment: You can use lastIndex in arraylist method. `list.lastIndexOf("apple")`

Comment: Thank you, i finally find everything that i need

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Output: [Apple, Grape, Mango]

```
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    arr.add("Apple");
    arr.add("Apple");
    arr.add("Apple");
    arr.add("Grape");
    arr.add("Mango");

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(arr);

    arr.clear();
    arr.addAll(set);

    System.out.println(set);
```

Comment: Seems like overkill, if you can use Set directly instead though!